# Differentiating a convolution-like integral

Tags: calculus, integration, functional-analysis, convolution

I have the following integral:

$\int_{0}^{t} f(t-\tau)g(\tau)d\tau\:g(t)$

The function $f(t)$ is known and $g(t)=C+\frac{1}{2}q(t)^2$, where C is some constant.

I want to differentiate the whole expression with respect to $q(t)$, but I am unsure how to exactly proceed since there is a $q(\tau)$ inside the integral.

Any hint on how to deal with this is much appreciated.

Comment: Is there supposed to be a $g(t)$ outside the integral? Also, how do you differentiate with respect to $q(t)$? You mean differentiate with respect to $t$?

Comment: There is supposed to be a $g(t)$ outside the integral. I do want to differentiate with respect to $q$, which in my problem depends on time $t$. So differentiation is not with respect to $t$. My problem is that I am not sure how to deal with the $q(\tau)$ inside the integral when differentiating wrt $q$.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way to go about it is to just solve for $\frac{dh(t,\tau)}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt}\int_{0}^{t} f(t-\tau)g(\tau)d\tau\:g(t)$, then if you can specify $q(t)$ and find the implicit equation for $\frac{dt}{dq}$ we can obtain the derivative with respect to $q$.

To take the actual derivative, it's probably best to use the [Leibniz Integral Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule).

Using that formula, I get:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{d}{dt} \int_{0}^{t} f(t-\tau)g(\tau)d\tau\:g(t) & = g(t)[f(0)g(t)+\int_0^t f'(t-\tau)g(\tau)d\tau] + g'(t)\int_0^tf(t-\tau)g(\tau)d\tau
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Now if you have a form for $q(t)$ we can find $\frac{dt}{dq}$, and multiply:

\begin{equation}
\frac{dh(t,\tau)}{dq} = \frac{dh(t,\tau)}{dt}\frac{dt}{dq}
\end{equation}